# cell value used for multiple pivot tables on a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a dashboard that runs on a worksheet.  The dashboard consists of multiple pivot tables from different data sources.

I want to be able to select from a dropdown the managers name to build this report and have that working fine.  The cell from the selection of the manager name is "vp_email_rm_rpt"

I have this working for one pivot table - however i have 6 .

How would i change this to let it loop to the next pivot table that is a different name and MAY have a different pivot field

I am close - but i keep running into an error.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Me.Range("rm_email_rm_rpt")
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then

 ' change revenue numbers
        With Sheets("RM_Rpt").PivotTables("RM_Account_List").PivotFields("LVL6_TERRITORY_EMAIL")
            .ClearAllFilters
            If Len(rng.Value) > 0 Then .CurrentPage = rng.Value
        End If
```

Comment: What error are your receiving? What line is the error happening on?

Comment: it works fine above, its when i start to try to get it to change another pivot table as well (more than one).   In the case above, i have a pivot table called "RM_Account_List" - i guess i dont know how to also include say "New_Pivot_tameble_Name_1" as well ...

Answer (score 0):

Your code just needs additional sections for each pivot table. You could in theory loop through all instead of specifically identifying each one, but for simplicity sake try the following. You'll just need to adjust the pivot table name and field name. If you need more, then keep adding them.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Me.Range("rm_email_rm_rpt")
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then

        ' change revenue numbers
        With Sheets("RM_Rpt").PivotTables("RM_Account_List").PivotFields("LVL6_TERRITORY_EMAIL")
            .ClearAllFilters
            If Len(rng.Value) > 0 Then .CurrentPage = rng.Value
        End With '<this line changes
        With Sheets("RM_Rpt").PivotTables("Pivot Table 2").PivotFields("LVL6_TERRITORY_EMAIL")
            .ClearAllFilters
            If Len(rng.Value) > 0 Then .CurrentPage = rng.Value
        End With '< This line too
    End If
End Sub
```

**Edit to respond to comment**

Just realized the error. You are starting a `With` statement, then closing it with an `End If` instead of an `End With`. I've updated the code above. Give that a try.

**Edit again to respond to comment**

Turns out I forgot an `End If`.

Comment: I get "end if without block if" ... i tried the same prior.  I don't know what "block if" means and haven't been able to figure out what i have been doing wrong.